# Unable to modify the font weight for the DispForm.aspx fields

Tags: page-layout, css, display-form

I want to change the font weight for the title, body, etc fields to be bold.
Using the IE tools I have identified that these title are within an h3 with class ms-standardheader. as follow:-

[image]

So inside my custom css I wrote the following :-

```
.ms-standardheader h3.ms-standardheader {
font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

But it did not change the font weight, can anyone advice what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Try changing your selector to `.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader` instead.

Comment: it worked well , can can you adive why mine code did not work ?

Comment: Your CSS was looking for an H3 with class "ms-standardheader" to was a descendant of an element with class "ms-standardheader"  Daniel's works because it has an appropriate parent class.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Daniel advice and used ".ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader" which solved my problems.

Comment: hi John- could you please autoaccept your answer? that way the question will appear as answered.